# DateTime.Now.ToString() timezone issue

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I upload a web-form in Azure-App Services, which link in to Azure-Sql database.

When user create a record, the aspx.cs generate a string and store in SQL server.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifyDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

When i run the code locally, the date+time works correctly. But when I run it in URL, it seems the new records are always 8 hours late. (exp: i save at 
 2019-5-23 15:00:00, SQL record became 2019-5-23 7:00:00) Since i was locate in Taiwan (GMT +8) I knew it has something to do with timezone.

Usually I'll spend hours testing the code, but not this time since the bug can't be fix locally, and publish app multiple times are time consuming.

```
sql = ("INSERT INTO MOrder (OrderDate, BranchID, SupplierID, ModifyDate) VALUES (@OrderDate, @Branch, @Supplier,@ModifyDate)");
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", datebox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifyDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", Session["Gbranch"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", Session["Gsuply"].ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Can someone modify my code so the Timestring can be stored properly? Thank you.

Comment: why you are not storing SQL datatime for moidydate field?

Comment: I would argue that your time strings _are_ stored properly. They are all in UTC. You don't have to store all the dates in your own time zone, right? You only need to change it to the user's time zone when you display it to the user.

Comment: Azure always uses the UTC timezone

Comment: @Kevin Shah Ill look into it, thanks :)

Comment: @Sweeper  I simply want to remove timezone factor, since user, developer are all in same timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you time to UTC before converting it to string.
Change this code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifyDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifyDate", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

when you read date string from server you need to Convert it back local time as follow.

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(Convert.ToDateTime("UTC Date time string"))
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: is the any specific reason for that ...does that improve performance ...?

Comment: thanks for suggestion i have updated it in the answer .

Comment: @JonSkeet: `It performs better and it's clearer`. Also, for that ambiguous hour every year in a timezone that uses daylight savings time, it gives the correct result, unlike `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime`

Comment: @Joe: No, `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()` gets that right due to a hidden "kind" that resolves the ambiguity. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/

Comment: @JonSkeet - interesting, I've learnt something new today.  Though as you hinted in your blog, the hidden "kind" generally won't survive serialization and deserialization, such as being passed as UTC across a WebAPI, so I wouldn't write code that relies on it.

Comment: @Joe: I'd generally avoid using DateTime entirely ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried DateTime.Now / DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime / DateTime.UtcNow and apparently they all generate same value. (always in GMT +0 , despite your current timezone)

I solved this problem by manually add 8 hours on top of it.

Here is my modified code (I am in Taiwan, GMT +8)

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifyDate", DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Thank you all for helping / recommending.